# How to create a link between HTML/JS and Django Admin

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, admin

I would like to create a 'select all' button for this
[booleans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiH4I.png) and I don't know how to do it.

I know it's hard to create a button like this with django admin so I have to use JS and HTML ?

How can I integrate HTML button and JS script into the django admin ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate JS, you can use `class Media`

By example:

```
class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("/static/js/admin/instantsearch.js",)
```

In order to change the admin templates of Django, you must create the folder `admin` in your `templates`.

Or else use:

```
template = "custom_template.html"
```

in your `ModelAdmin` class

But in general, better read about [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am a C# developer 
put simply for the first question : 
I can advice you to make a loop for all boxes and change them state (value Checked)